# .gitignore file for wavemaker 6.4.6

Tags: git, push, gitignore, wavemaker

I need a help about gitignore file and pulling/pushing wavemaker project (6.4.6 version) on bitbucket repository.

I founded that gitignore must contains these:

http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmdoc_6.5/Software+Configuration+Management#HExamplegitignorefile

but this is for version 6.5 and this is not good for version 6.4.6.

I pushed a project to the repository  and when my colleague tried to pull the latest version from repository, then the project can not be opened because it have error 
like this:
ErrorFailed to open project : SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===

I know that wavemaker generate some of files, and both of us have project export, but when one of us push the new code on repository, then other after pulling can't open the project.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error doesn't sound like the result of an incorrect .gitignore.

The WaveMaker 6.5 .gitignore contains excludes for files that do not exist in WaveMaker 6.4. WM 6.4 does not have a phonegap build or timestamp.txt for example. So there's nothing to exclude there.

If you ignored a required file, a missing file error seems more likely.

I'd suggest finding where the "===" is in the project files. Whatever is failing to parse the file containing that syntax should be telling you what file it is working on.